# tinyMCE editor version 3 upload image option

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce-4, tinymce-3

i am using tinyMCE 3 for my project. Unfortunately image upload option is not by default. I am trying by adding some code, but its not working with tinyMCE v3. See its not giving option to browse image.

[image]

Here is what i am doing :

```
tinyMCE.init({
    mode : "textareas",
    theme : "advanced",
    plugin : 'imgmanager',
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : 'imgmanager'
});
```

But its not working for me.

Comment: You mean it doesn't show the "Image List" dropdown below the "Image URL"?

Comment: No, its not giving browse button to upload image directly from my system

Comment: Your screenshot in your question is from the standard image button of the advanced editor it is not a screenshot from the plugin "imgmanager" you are using. I think you are pressing the wrong image button in your editor. You have to find the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Like my comment you are not pressing the correct button (probably you have not configured correctly `tinyMCE` and it is not displaying your plugin's button)
Below is the configuration that worked for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinyMCE.init({
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "advanced",
        plugins : 'imgmanager',
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "imgmanager",
    });
</script>
```

Notice **`plugin`** is wrong, it should be **`plugins`**

Of course make sure you have copied the `imgmanager` plugin to yours tinyMCE installation `plugins` folder.

Here is a screenshot of mine:

[image]

The plugin button is on the upper left corner.

**UPDATE**

For configuration instructions please have a look here: http://www.binpress.com/app/tinymce-3x-image-manager-and-editor/781

Comment: Great! are you able to upload image now?

Comment: Me? No I haven't tried, I just downloaded `tinyMCE` sources to help you out, and ran everything from client (file://....) and many features of `tinyMCE` do not work as expected. Can you try it on your own? In the plugin's documentation it mentions that an `upload` folder must exist and be accessible for read/write

Comment: Plus I think you need to have `PHP` for this plugin in order to work, is your application/project in `PHP`?